# Error while generation gerber files

Tags: orcad, gerber

I've created a layout and I want to generate gerber files for further production. I'm using Cadence OrCAD software. But when I try to Create Artwork, I'm getting an error.

[image]

I've checked the dbdoctor file and there's an error that applies to the logo in the silkscreen

```
ERROR: in ARC SEGMENT center = (-113.118 2.774)
  class = PACKAGE GEOMETRY
  subclass = SILKSCREEN_TOP 
  Part of Symbol Def LOGO_18X10MM_SILKSCREEN.
  ERROR(SPMHUT-144): Illegal arc specification.

0 warnings, 1 errors detected, 0 errors could be fixed.
```

I tried to delete some curved segments but it didn't solve the problem. How can I approach that problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you deleted the exact illegal arc at (-113.118 2.774)? Remember to put global visibility on so nothing is hidden.

Comment: did you do what the message tells you to do?

Comment: Hi @Bonnevie. That point is far away from the PCB outline. There's no element in that coordination. When I delete the logo in the silkscreen, the problem disappears

Comment: Can you manually redraw the logo? There must be something wrong with it (in the eyes of cadence).

Comment: It would be nice to get to the bottom of it, but maybe you can just get around it by manually re-drawing the logo.

Comment: Ah yes that is where I have experienced it before: importing logos and pictures.
I it does not work, you will have to reimport with different settings. It is very trial and error. But I think it can work regardless of the picture, I once imported a cartoon figure to the back of a PCB, after a few tries ofc.